# OpenPGP specification and ECC

Tags: gnupg

From OpenPGP specification (RFC 4880) section 13.8 (Reserved Algorithm Numbers):

> The reserved public-key algorithms, Elliptic Curve (18), ECDSA (19),
>   and X9.42 (21), do not have the necessary parameters, parameter
>   order, or semantics defined.

But GnuPG has ECC support. What they use as a reference? How other developers could support ECC and read messages from GnuPG with ECC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While OpenPGP in the current revision is defined by RFC 4880, there are two additional RFCs providing extensions:

- [RFC 5581](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5581) defines the Camellia Cipher in OpenPGP
- [RFC 6637](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6637) defines elliptic curve cryptography in OpenPGP

Furthermore, a [draft for EdDSA signatures](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-koch-eddsa-for-openpgp/) is already proposed. GnuPG 2.1 already implements this draft.

Comment: There is also an Internet Draft for EdDSA / ed25519 support in OpenPGP: http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-koch-eddsa-for-openpgp/

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I extended the answer accordingly.